# knockout js json bind list to clicked listitem

Tags: javascript, json, data-binding, knockout.js, binding

I would like to select a specific location by Continent / Country / State / etc.
I get a JSON and I managed to display/select the Continent, but I cannot get the list of Countries to populate.

I am rather new to knockout and JS, so I am probably doing something wrong (I managed to do this based on the live examples from knockout, but those were using select, and I cannot seem to get it to work on ul)

The JSON (composed by hand, so might have errors)

```
var Continent = [
        { Name: "Europe", Countries: [{ Name: "England", ID: 1 }, { Name: "Wales", ID: 2 }] },
        { Name: "America", Countries: [{ Name: "US", ID: 3 }, { Name: "Canada", ID: 4 }] },
        { Name: "Asia", Countries: [{ Name: "India", ID: 5 }, { Name: "China", ID: 6 }] }
];
```

The javascript:

```
var locationVM = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.selectedContinent = ko.observable("none");
    self.selectedCountry = ko.observable();

    self.selectedContinent.subscribe(function () {
        self.selectedCountry(undefined);
    });

    self.onClickContinent = function (data) {
        self.selectedContinent(data.Name);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new locationVM());
```

The HTML

```
<div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: Continent">
        <li data-bind="text: Name, click: $parent.onClickContinent" />
    </ul>
</div>Selected Continent : <span data-bind="text: selectedContinent">text</span>

<div data-bind="with: selectedContinent">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: Countries">
        <li data-bind="text: Name" />
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/norbert/WB46V/

Also, if there is anything I missed, or is not needed, please point it out, or provide link for further studies ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set the continent value to a string and then later trying to iterate thru the string. What you need to do is set the continent to the data.

Something like this:

```
self.selectedContinent(data);
```

Working fiddle here.
http://jsfiddle.net/WB46V/6/

Just to add, I haven't used knockout before, so my solution in the fiddle might not be the best one.